# Treat two different sets of columns as a single index and column when pivoting

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('xyz'), 'freq_a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': list('axy'), 'freq_b': [3, 4, 5], 'c': list('bzy'), 'freq_c': [5, 6, 7]})
df
   a  freq_a  b  freq_b  c  freq_c
0  x       1  a       3  b       5
1  y       2  x       4  z       6
2  z       3  y       5  y       7
```

I want to group each value in `a`, `b`, `c` columns like the example below that is for the value `x`.

```
x freq_a 1
  freq_b 4
  freq_c NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `filter` then we `concat` them, now the problem is like find the missing level so we using `stack` + `unstack`

```
s=df.filter(like='freq')
pd.concat([s.stack(),df.drop(s.columns,1).add_prefix('freq_').stack()],1).\
     reset_index(level=1).\
         set_index([1,'level_1']).\
            sort_index(0)[0].unstack().stack(dropna=False)

1  level_1
a  freq_a     NaN
   freq_b     3.0
   freq_c     NaN
b  freq_a     NaN
   freq_b     NaN
   freq_c     5.0
x  freq_a     1.0
   freq_b     4.0
   freq_c     NaN
y  freq_a     2.0
   freq_b     5.0
   freq_c     7.0
z  freq_a     3.0
   freq_b     NaN
   freq_c     6.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reshape and pivot. From there, just choose which variable you want.

```
res = (
 df.filter(like='freq')
   .melt()
   .assign(label=df[['a', 'b', 'c']].values.ravel())
   .pivot_table(index='label', columns='variable', values='value', aggfunc='first'))

res

variable  freq_a  freq_b  freq_c
label                          
a            2.0     NaN     NaN
b            3.0     NaN     NaN
x            1.0     4.0     NaN
y            NaN     3.0     6.0
z            NaN     5.0     5.0
```

```
res.loc['x']                                                                                       

variable
freq_a    1.0
freq_b    4.0
freq_c    NaN
Name: x, dtype: float64

res.loc[['x']]                                                                                     

variable  freq_a  freq_b  freq_c
label                          
x            1.0     4.0     NaN
```